# Quickly find string in long array

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, hash

I have a very long array (~2 million) of strings (ISBN for books).

I am parsing an XML file that adds to my existing library. Instead of hitting the database on every book in the XML file, I've loaded the existing library of ISBNs into an array.

If a new ISBN is found, I create a new book model. If the already ISBN exists, I update a column for that title.

Currently using index to find each ISBN from the XML file

```
array.index(ISBN)
```

I also experimented with converting the array to a hash of ISBN keys and that's a little faster.

```
hash[ISBN]
```

Any ideas to do the lookup faster? Both the array and hash method are giving me roughly 15 and 20 checks/sec respectively.

Comment: How about bloom filter? https://github.com/igrigorik/bloomfilter-rb

Comment: What unit is `mm`? Normally, that means milimeter, which does not make sense here.

Comment: sorry, mm = million. updated

Answer (score 0):

Hash lookup is the fastest you can get, I think. Its computational complexity is a constant with respect to the size. If that is not fast enough, there should be something wrong with other parts of your code.

Comment: Yeah, that seems in-line with most other posts I've read. But some of those discussions were several years old so just wanting to confirm that hash keys are still the way to go